# Evento click en solo el elemento clickeado

Tags: javascript, html, css, eventos, script

Mi problema es el siguiente, nesecito que al dar un click con el mouse sobre un elemento de html, se ejecute el evento click solamente sobre el elemento clickeado y no que se ejecute en los otros elementos que comparten el mismo llamado.

[image: elementos sin dar click]

[image: elementos al dar click en uno solo]

No pude incrustar coodigo asi que muestro en un pantallazo el script que estoy utilizando

[image: script]

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();

$(document).ready(function() {
  if( document.documentElement.clientWidth < 2000 ){
    $('#block-quicktabs-beneficios .campos-grupo-ciudades .views-field-field-ciudad span').on('click', function(){  
        if ($('#block-quicktabs-beneficios .campos-grupo-beneficios .campos-grupo-ciudades .views-field-field-ciudad > .field-content').is(':hidden')) {
            $('#block-quicktabs-beneficios .campos-grupo-ciudades .views-field-field-ciudad span').off('click', 'span');
            $('#block-quicktabs-beneficios .campos-grupo-beneficios .campos-grupo-ciudades .views-field-field-ciudad > .field-content').addClass('claseuqemesirveporfavor');    
            $('#block-quicktabs-beneficios .campos-grupo-beneficios .campos-grupo-ciudades .views-field-field-ciudad > .field-content.claseuqemesirveporfavor').show();

        } else {   
          $('#block-quicktabs-beneficios .campos-grupo-beneficios .campos-grupo-ciudades .views-field-field-ciudad > .field-content.claseuqemesirveporfavor').hide(); 
          $('#block-quicktabs-beneficios .campos-grupo-beneficios .campos-grupo-ciudades .views-field-field-ciudad > .field-content').removeClass('claseuqemesirveporfavor');

        }
    });  
  }
  else{
    $('#block-quicktabs-beneficios .campos-grupo-beneficios .campos-grupo-ciudades .views-field-field-ciudad > .field-content').hide();
  }
});

var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

Este es el html:

```
<div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">     
<div class="views-field views-field-field-logo-imagen-convenio">        
    <div class="field-content"><a href="/beneficios/spacios"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://fincom.geosdigital.org/sites/default/files/styles/convenio-logo/public/unnamed%20%282%29_0.png?itok=TlGPcSER" width="120" height="120" alt=""></a>
    </div>
</div>  

<div class="campos-grupo-beneficios views-fieldset" data-module="views_fieldsets">
    <div class="views-field views-field-field-t-tulo-corto"><h2 class="field-content"></h2>
    </div>      
    <div class="views-field views-field-body"><span class="field-content"><p>Servicio de asesoría en decoración para hacer de tu vivienda un lugar con estilo y elegancia...</p></span>
    </div>      
    <div class="campos-grupo-ciudades views-fieldset" data-module="views_fieldsets">
        <div class="views-field views-field-field-ciudad"><span class="views-label views-label-field-ciudad">Ver Cuidades</span><div class="field-content">Bogotá
    </div>
</div>      
<div class="views-field views-field-view-node"><span class="field-content"><a href="/beneficios/spacios">Más info</a></span>
</div>
```

**

### Gracias a MaximoSL ya que logré lo que queria con su sugerencia y por supuesto a todos lo que me brindaron sus aportes.

**

Comment: **Es importante que leas [ask]** el código lo debes subir como texto usando las herramientas que ofrece el editor de texto de Stackoverflow para una mejor lectura y comprensión del mismo

Comment: Es preferible que copies el código sin formatear (luego podemos editar nosotros la pregunta y hacerlo) que el que pongas una imagen. una imagen con el código fuente NUNCA es bienvenida porque no podemos copiarlo, modificarlo o hacer fácilmente pruebas para responderte

Comment: Es importante que agregues el código como texto, debido a que muchas personas que quieren ayudarte lo primero que hacemos es correr el código para tratar de ver donde está el error. Si no facilitas el código como tal, es mu dificil que alguien lo transcriba.

Comment: Intente añadir el codigo en texto pero se veia desordenado.

Comment: @MiguelAngel no importa, nosotros editamos la pregunta y lo arreglamos :D

Comment: al parecer es muy garnd el codigo

Comment: Bueno edite la pregunta y en la parte inferior esta el codigo, desordenado pero esta.

Answer (score 2):

podrías agregar la clase al elemento y eliminarla de sus hermanos
`$('.field-content').addClass('clasequemesirveporfavor').siblings().removeClass('clasequemesirveporfavor');`

Comment: Maximo soy nuevo en esto, asi que mi duda es si con esa linea de codigo aun funciona al dar click o si funciona con hover?

Comment: @Miguel Angel Si funciona checa este [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maximosl/uw3830b3/)

Comment: Maximo, esta tremendo ese efecto, pero no me funcionó lastimosamente, aunque creo que para algo futuro me va a funcionar de maravilla. :)

Comment: MaximoSL hoy ya con mas calma revice mi codigo y analice mucho mejor el tuyo y funcionó :) mil gracias por tu ayuda, eres un capo.

Answer (score 0):

no me di a la tarea de ver todo tu codigo pero puedes usar identificadores o apuntar con una clase, pones de la siguiente manera:

```
$('.class').on('click', function(){$(this).show();});
```

el this es para apuntar al elemento que se le dio click y no todos los elementos que tienen la clase '.class'

Comment: Carlos, lo voy a intentar con con esta sugerencia.

Comment: O no funciona, o meti el codigo donde no era, que podrá ser??? :(

Answer (score 0):

En base a tu código yo lo haría de la siguiente forma:

Por medio del `$(this)` y de la función `closest()` podemos interactuar únicamente con los elementos que sean familiares del `<span>` al cual se le dio click.

```js
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();

$(document).ready(function() {
    if(document.documentElement.clientWidth < 2000 ){
        $('#block-quicktabs-beneficios .campos-grupo-ciudades .views-field-field-ciudad span').on('click', function(){ 
            if ($(this).closest("#block-quicktabs-beneficios").find('.campos-grupo-beneficios .campos-grupo-ciudades .views-field-field-ciudad > .field-content').is(':hidden')) {
                $(this).closest("#block-quicktabs-beneficios").find('.campos-grupo-ciudades .views-field-field-ciudad span').off('click', 'span');
                $(this).closest("#block-quicktabs-beneficios").find('.campos-grupo-beneficios .campos-grupo-ciudades .views-field-field-ciudad > .field-content').addClass('claseuqemesirveporfavor');
                $(this).closest("#block-quicktabs-beneficios").find('.campos-grupo-beneficios .campos-grupo-ciudades .views-field-field-ciudad > .field-content.claseuqemesirveporfavor').show();
            } else {   
                $(this).closest("#block-quicktabs-beneficios").find('.campos-grupo-beneficios .campos-grupo-ciudades .views-field-field-ciudad > .field-content.claseuqemesirveporfavor').hide(); 
                $(this).closest("#block-quicktabs-beneficios").find('.campos-grupo-beneficios .campos-grupo-ciudades .views-field-field-ciudad > .field-content').removeClass('claseuqemesirveporfavor');
            }
        });  
    }else{
        $('#block-quicktabs-beneficios .campos-grupo-beneficios .campos-grupo-ciudades .views-field-field-ciudad > .field-content').hide();
    }
});

var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Comment: Camilo, gracias por la ayuda, pero tampoco me funcionó, no se que estaré haciendo mal. :(

Comment: Te saca errores o algo ? Revisa la consola

Comment: ya miro consola, aunque lo que he podido ver del codigo en vivo es que le pone la clase a todos los elementos del html

Comment: Es raro por que con $(this) se restringe eso, necesitaría ver tu flujo de nodos completo

Comment: Camilo gracias por tu enorme ayuda, pero ya lo solucioné con el aporte de MaximoSL

Comment: @MiguelAngel me alegra que encontraras la solución, si la respuesta de MaximoSL fue la solución del problema considera marcarla como aceptada, saludos !

Comment: Se que no es el único camino, pues algo estaría haciendo mal con el anterior codigo, para que tu aporte no me haya funcionado.

Comment: @MiguelAngel lo lindo de la programación es que hay mil caminos a seguir para realizar algo en concreto, pero en este caso y según como funciona el sitio la respuesta fue la que solucionó tu problema por eso merece ser marcada como aceptada :D